# Why is my rinkeby balance is 0 after syncing even though transaction shows ether was sent

Tags: rinkeby

Could you please help me to find out what I’m doing wrong.
I’ve topped up my test accounts from https://faucet.rinkeby.io/. When I check their balances on https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/balancecheck-tool,  I can see that both of them have 3 ethers each. The accounts are: ‘0x402596a354411c73a3fe8e99ba1e7226fe88361c’ and ‘0x6403e1c470f3bb7f0f1bd23756624e0293f98079’.

But when I open a connection with Rinkeby test network using this command: `geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="personal, eth, network, web3, net" --ipcpath "~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc"` (I left my computer for night to get all the updates from Rinkeby) and on the other tab open Geth console (`geth attach`) and run `eth.syncing` I see that my local network is updated. But when I run `eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1])` or `eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[2])` to see the balances of my funded accounts I see 0.

What am I doing wrong? Could you please help me overcoming this issue? I will be so grateful to you! This problem is driving me insane...

Comment: What is your latest local block number?

Comment: If I run ```eth.getBlock("latest")``` is 0, if we talk about "eth.syncing" it's almost finished and above the block where my transaction happened